# Why does Mathematica give the wrong answer when integrating?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 9.0.0**

---

I integrate

```
Integrate[Exp[I Cos[b - c]] Cos[b], {b, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Mathematica gives:

```
2 I Pi BesselJ[1, 1]
```

Which is indepedent on $c$. However, the result is NOT independent on $c$.

The numerical value of what Mathematica gives is `0. + 2.76492 I` while

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I Cos[b - 0.5]] Cos[b], {b, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Gives

```
1.16655*10^-10 + 2.42645 I
```

Certainly not the same. If we multiply the value Mathematica gives with $\cos(0.5)$ the result is the same. What is wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like a bug that ran off in the development version of Mathematica.

```
In[1]:= Integrate[Exp[I Cos[b - c]] Cos[b], {b, 0, 2 Pi}]//InputForm

Out[1]//InputForm= (2*I)*Pi*BesselJ[1, 1]*Cos[c]

In[2]:= %/.c->.5

Out[2]= 0. + 2.42645 I
```

Comment: What do you mean? I use 8.0.4.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen he's referring to the fact that the bug no longer shows up in the development version, i.e. a version that hasn't been released to the public, yet.

Comment: Hmm, right. But how do I fix this? My project doesn't work when this is wrong! And how can I now trust the output? I can't check all these horrendous integrals by hand, I was using Mathematica to *not* make mistakes.

Comment: Numeric checks like the one you did seem like a good way to go about the checking process.

Comment: Right... That implies that I have to check a few hundred of them with many parameters :-). Of course, any program can have a bug, but it still is *very* annoying.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau So when can we all be beta-testers of the development version? Somehow to me it makes no sense to mention unreleased versions publicly without providing the readers at least some kind of possibility to test and use the great new bug-fixed-version.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Try to make a list of basic integrals yourself, test the list, make it into a function with some algebra and pattern matching and then you are independent of the Mathematica version. I did this for a special class of integrals I needed a long time ago for FeynCalc : http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Integrate2/ and http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Integrate3/

Comment: @Rolf Cool stuff!

Comment: @Rolf Would you prefer that we not comment on bugs? That's the only alternative to what I did, as you are well aware.

Comment: @Daniel I find all the feedback about bugs encouraging.  Even though your answer doesn't fix the problem here and now, it is good to see that these problems get paid attention to and that fixes are on the way.  I'd appreciate if WRI people kept commenting on bugs in public like this.

Answer (score 8):

This bug appears to have been known for over a year now! [See the mathGroup archive](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/integrate%2420bessel%2420function%2420bug%7Csort%3adate/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/ofJh_oRFAB4/TFcbpQsKw3MJ)

**Edit**

To explain why I consider these bugs to be equivalent, I'll re-write the two integrals using the integration variable `x`. In the present question, we have $$I_1(c)=\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(i\cos(x-c))\cos x\,dx$$

On the other hand, the MathGroup post I linked here considers the integral 
$$I_2(c)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp(i\cos(x-c))\exp(ix-ic)\,dx$$
where I specialized to the case giving the same Bessel argument in the result. Pulling out the constant factor, using the periodicity of the integrand and making a substitution of variables, one finds
$$I_2(c)=e^{-ic}\left[I_1(c)+i\, I_1(c-\frac{\pi}{2})\right]$$

Therefore, if Wolfram fixed the bug in the calculation of $I_2$ but still gets an incorrect result for $I_1$, that fix was itself incorrect. This argument generalizes to integer Bessel indices other than 1 (which is what this question has).

Finally, the question is whether it is a bug fix to return the integrals unevaluated. I would argue that because these are such ubiquitous integrals, Mathematica should definitely know what to do with them. But I may not have all the information as to why this bug is so hard to fix... I just wanted to briefly clarify my thinking in case anyone cares.

Comment: They actually seem to be opposites in some sense, so I doubt it's the same bug.

Comment: No - it's the exact same thing.

Comment: Jonas is getting `<constant>*<BesselJ>` instead of an expected `<constant>*<BesselJ><f[otherVariable]>`.  

The MathGroup poster is getting `<constant>*<BesselJ><f[otherVariable]>` instead of `<constant>*<BesselJ>`.  

They may be related, but that's enough to classify them as separate bugs in my book.

Comment: The fix to one was to disable it from giving any result. This may be why the other will in a future release give the correct result. But its not as simple one change causing BOTH to give a correct result.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Not sure if you noticed the edit here. Could you comment on this?

Comment: I think the two are related, in terms of Mathematica Integrate internals. Clearly they are related mathematically.