# Integration with Bessel function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, undocumented

I know that the integration of:

```
Integrate`InverseIntegrate[Exp[-x Cosh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Re[x] > 0]
```

is:

```
BesselK[0, x].
```

I would like to integrate the following expression, using the same procedure:

```
Integrate`InverseIntegrate[Exp[-x Cosh[t] - t], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Re[x] > 0]
```

The integration fails.

The result should be:

```
BesselK[1, x]-Exp[-x]/x
```

What can I do?

Comment: what does  ``Integrate`InverseIntegrate`` supposed to do? Where is this function documented? How can one answer this without knowing what  does ``Integrate`InverseIntegrate`` mean? I do not see it documented anywhere?  It helps if you explain more what this is supposed to do.

Comment: In principle I want only to integrate. For this I found the following link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/incorrect-results-for-elementary-integrals-when-using-integrate/6695#6695. `Integrate[Exp[-x Cosh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity}]`does not solve.
 `

Comment: See also: ?Integrate`*

Comment: thanks, I did `?Integrate`* before, but it only gave ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KHL5T.png) which did not say much about what this is supposed to do, that is why I asked ;)

Comment: Of course, I meant I added a little explanation to [(4728)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4728), but dyslexia struck.

Comment: @Michael E2: Please see my comment in your answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/incorrect-results-for-elementary-integrals-when-using-integrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal function `` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] `` tries what I call the "obvious" substitutions, namely, `u == g[x]`, where `g[x]` appears as the argument to a function in the expression being integrated.  The problem here is that `Power` automatically combines the product

```
Exp[-x Cosh[t]] * Exp[-t]
```

into a single power. If we try `TrigToExp@Exp[-x Cosh[t] - t]`, we again cannot separate out the `Exp[-t]` from the integrand.  Even if we enter

```
TrigToExp@Exp[-x Cosh[t]] Exp[-t]
(*  E^(-t - 1/2 (E^-t + E^t) x) *)
```

the factor `Exp[-t]` is combined with the other factor. This keeps `` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] `` from identifying `u = Exp[t] + Exp[-t]` as the substitution to try.

The substitution @mrz shows, `u == Exp[-t]` is tried by `` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] ``, and it gets one step from the solution, by using
`` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] `` again. But `` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] `` is applied only once, so it fails.  In fact, after the first substitution, `` Integrate`InverseIntegrate `` is set equal to `$Failed &`, preventing any further application of it.

Here's a way to get Mathematica to try two applications of `` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] ``.  Basically, we make a copy of it, and have `Integrate` call it under suitable conditions.

```
ClearAll[int];
DownValues[int] = 
  DownValues[Integrate`InverseIntegrate] /. Integrate`InverseIntegrate -> int;
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate},
 Unprotect[Integrate];
 Integrate[i_, {x_, a_, b_}, stuff___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := 
  Block[{$in = True, res}, 
   If[FreeQ[{stuff}, 
     Conditional`InertUndefined | ConditionalExpression],
    If[a < b,
     res = int[i, {x, a, b}, stuff],
     res = int[-i, {x, b, a}, stuff]
     ],
    res = $Failed
    ];
   If[FreeQ[res, $Failed],
    res,
    Integrate[i, {x, a, b}, stuff]
    ]];
 Protect[Integrate];
 Assuming[Re[x] > 0,
  Integrate`InverseIntegrate[
   TrigToExp@Exp[-x Cosh[t] - t], {t, 0, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> Re[x] > 0]
  ]]

(*  (E^-x (-1 + E^x x BesselK[1, x]))/x  *)
```

Here's a way to do the substitution manually and use `Integrate[]` instead of `` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] ``:

```
Assuming[Re[x] > 0 && t > 0 && u > 2,
  TrigToExp[Exp[-x Cosh[t] - t] Dt[t] /.            (* integrand *)
      First@Solve[2 Cosh[t] == u && t > 0, t]] /.   (* substitution *)
   _Dt -> 1 // Simplify];
(Numerator[%] (u - Sqrt[-4 + u^2])) /               (* rationalize, in part *)
  Expand[Denominator[%] (u - Sqrt[-4 + u^2])]
(*  (E^(-((u x)/2)) (u - Sqrt[-4 + u^2]))/(2 Sqrt[-4 + u^2])  *)

Integrate[%, {u, 2, Infinity}, Assumptions -> Re[x] > 0]
(*  -(E^-x/x) + BesselK[1, x]  *)
```

For some reason, `Integrate[]` cannot solve the unrationalized expression.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Wolfram Technical Support:

Consider just what's under the integral

```
Exp[-x*Cosh[t]-t]dt 
= Exp[-x*Cosh[t]]*Exp[-t]dt 
= Exp[-(x/2)*(Exp[-t]+Exp[t])]*Exp[-t]dt
```

Now, make the `u` substitution

```
u=Exp[-t]
du=-Exp[-t]dt
```

Thus, the Integrand is

```
-Exp[-(x/2)*(u+1/u)]du
```

and the integral runs from 1 to 0. We can then flip the limits of integration and eliminate the minus sign out front. With the integral in this form, we can get the desired result.

```
Integrate`InverseIntegrate[Exp[-(x/2)*(u + 1/u)], {u, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> Re[x] > 0]

(E^-x (-1 + E^x x BesselK[1, x]))/x
```

Using FullSimplify, we get the result in the form you are looking for.

```
FullSimplify[%]

-(E^-x/x) + BesselK[1, x]
```