# Bug in Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages, convergence

In v. 11.1.0.0 Mathematica for Linux

`Integrate[Sin[Cosh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity}]`

returns

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of Sin[Cosh[t]] does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}.

while the integral is clearly bounded.

`NIntegrate[Sin[Cosh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity}]`

seems to return a finite value.

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: this is very highly oscillatory function. Are you sure it is `NIntegrate` which got it right, and not `Integrate`?  `Intergate` can not integrate the indefinite integral also. So it must have done some checking before.

Comment: @Nasser I think it converges, but I don't know whether it can be computed by *Mathematica* in terms of known functions.

Comment: In summary: please report this to Support.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the integral in question converges conditionally and can be calculated after substituting $x = \cosh(t)$, giving (on the integration domain) $$t = \text{arccosh}(x), \;\; dt = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$$

```
Integrate[Sin[x]/Sqrt[x^2 - 1], {x, 1, ∞}]
```

> ```
> 1/2 π BesselJ[0, 1]
> ```

```
N[%]
```

> ```
> 1.20197
> ```

We can numerically integrate over a large finite range, forcing each zero to be integrated over. This will ensure we're not skipping over any peaks or valleys.

```
NIntegrate[Sin[Cosh[t]], {t, ##}] & @@ Prepend[ArcCosh[π Range[10000]], 0]
```

> ```
> 1.20194
> ```

This extended syntax of `NIntegrate` is discussed [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html#19295).

Comment: That is different from NIntegrate[Sin[Cosh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity}] that gives 0.910823.

Answer (score 11):

Using the *undocumented* function [`` Integrate`InverseIntegrate[] ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6695):

```
Integrate`InverseIntegrate[Sin[Cosh[t]], {t, 0, ∞}]
   1/2 π BesselJ[0, 1]

N[%, 20]
   1.2019697153172064991
```

which is consistent with Chip's reformulation:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[x]/Sqrt[x^2 - 1], {x, 1, ∞}, 
           Method -> "DoubleExponentialOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   1.2019697153164287403
```