# Mathematica and special functions

Tags: syntax, special-functions

How is it possible that *Mathematica* doesn't recognize it's own definitions of special functions ? I tried as input:

```
Integrate[Cosh[I2t]/E^(6 Cosh[t]), {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

The above should give $K_{i2}(6)$ according to [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/07/ShowAll.html). Unfortunately, it just happily reproduces my input, and leaves me ignorant of how it should have been phrased.

Does someone know how I could get *Mathematica* recognize to evaluate such input to something useful?

Moreover, when I plot

```
Plot[BesselK[2 I, z], {z, 0, 7}]
```

I get a graph, but when I evaluate

```
BesselK[2 I, 6]
```

again, *Mathematica* repeats my input.

I'm not really used to *Mathematica*, so sometimes I get this sort of frustrating output, *Mathematica* not understanding what I'm trying to say.

Comment: 1. `I2t` is treated as a single variable; put spaces in between variables that you intend to multiply. 2. `BesselK[2 I, 6]` is an *exact* number without an apparently simpler closed form; to see an *approximation*, use `N[]`: `N[BesselK[2 I, 6]]`.

Comment: What makes you think this transformation rule is in *Mathematica*? While related, the *Wolfram Functions* site is not a source for *Mathematica* transformation rules per se...

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. You'll become the first portable computerless computer language interpreter

Comment: Not quite yet there, @bel. :)

Comment: Closely related: [Incorrect results for elementary integrals when using Integrate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4728/245). Unfortunately the solution there (Integrate`InverseIntegrate) doesn't work in general. Also related: [Why does Mathematica give the wrong answer when integrating?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2740/245).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mathematica* does not recognize your integral is `BesselK[2 I, 6]` even though it is. All the identities shown on http://functions.wolfram.com are not necessarily incorporated into *Mathematica*. The numeric equivalence of `BesselK[2 I, 6]` and the integral can be demonstrated by

```
N[BesselK[2 I, 6], 16] == 
  NIntegrate[Cosh[2 I t]/E^(6 Cosh[t]), {t, 0, ∞},
    PrecisionGoal -> 16, 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> "MultipanelRule"}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```